# Why is my layout breaking?

Tags: css, magento

I've been trying to use Firebug to inspect the elements on my page to see why the pruduct image is dropping down below the configuration box on the right instead of being near the top of the page without much luck. Can anyone see what the issue is?

I've asked the theme developer and they said that Cart2Quote plun breaks the Argeto layout. I'm sure I can tweak the CSS and fix this but I can't find the issue. Can anyone see the problem?

http://dev.globalamericaninc.com/index.php/le-37i-g-3-5-embedded-mini-board-with-intel-skylake-6th-gen-core-h-series-processor.html

Comment: This same feature extension is compatible with any theme https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 1):

you must have an element (or more) that has {clear : left} or {clear : both} in the right side. Google what clear does in CSS

Comment: I figure there is some issue like that but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

change below CSS rules:

```
default.css line 742
.product-view .product-img-box {
  float: left;
  width: 445px;
}

default.css line 746
.product-view .product-shop, .col1-layout .product-view .product-shop {
  float: right;
  /*
  float: none;
  margin-left: 385px;
  width: auto;
  */
}
```

Comment: This works. Ultimately I went back and resinstalled the plugin and that seems to have fixed the issue.